# Make entire inline-block div as hyperlink

Tags: html, css

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shawn-zhang-the-decoder/pen/jgWNzB). I want to make the entire cube (div) act as a hyperlink. I can do so by wrapping  around it. However, since the cube has `display: inline-block;`, the hyperlink actually wraps to below the cube as well. If you hover below the cube, you can find it.

What should I do to take away that link at the bottom — while keeping the cube to be `inline-block`?

Here is the code:

```
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="flippety">
            <h1>Flippity</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="flop">
            <h2>Flop</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

```
/* Set-up */
body {
    color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: #F4F6F8;
    padding: 3em 0 0 0;
    line-height: 62px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px; 
}

/* Container box to set the sides relative to */
.cube {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
    transition: transform .33s; /* Animate the transform properties */

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; /* <-NB */
}

/* The two faces of the cube */
.flippety,.flop {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
    height: 200px;
}

/* Position the faces */
.flippety {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.flop {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
}

/* Rotate the cube */
.cube:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the inline-block and width to `a` element

```css
/* Set-up */

body {
  color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #F4F6F8;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  line-height: 62px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}


/* Container box to set the sides relative to */

.cube {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .33s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* The two faces of the cube */

.flippety,
.flop {
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  height: 200px;
}


/* Position the faces */

.flippety {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.flop {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
}


/* Rotate the cube */

.cube:hover {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="flippety">
      <h1>Flippity</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flop">
      <h2>Flop</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Or simply make the cube your `a` element and avoid an extra element:

```css
/* Set-up */

body {
  color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #F4F6F8;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  line-height: 62px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

a.cube {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .33s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* The two faces of the cube */

.flippety,
.flop {
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  height: 200px;
}


/* Position the faces */

.flippety {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.flop {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
}


/* Rotate the cube */

.cube:hover {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com" target="_blank" class="cube">
    <div class="flippety">
      <h1>Flippity</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flop">
      <h2>Flop</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS to your wrapper `<a>` tag

```
a {
   display: block;
   height: 200px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/ZgQzMr

Comment: This was one of my problems. Now, you can see that the hyperlink expanded horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps consider using JavaScript to create a click event on the cube and remove the anchor from the equation:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("cube")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
}, false);
```

```css
/* Set-up */

body {
  color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #F4F6F8;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  line-height: 62px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}


/* Container box to set the sides relative to */

.cube {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
  transition: transform .33s;
  /* Animate the transform properties */
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* <-NB */
}


/* The two faces of the cube */

.flippety,
.flop {
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  height: 200px;
}


/* Position the faces */

.flippety {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.flop {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-100px);
}


/* Rotate the cube */

.cube:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  /* Text bleed at 90º */
}
```

```html
<!-- <a href="example.com" target="_blank"> -->
<div class="cube">
  <div class="flippety">
    <h1>Flippity</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flop">
    <h2>Flop</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </a> -->
```